# Can we uninstall/remove Google Workspace Marketplace App from organization using API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-workspace, google-api-nodejs-client

basically user can manually uninstall app, but we want uninstall app using any RestAPI using access Token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to uninstall an app on behalf of a user with the API since there is no existing API method to achieve this.

What you can do instead is to use the `tokens.delete` method to remove the access of the app to the user's account, however the user will still be able to see the app installed for them and would just need to authorize the app once again to have the access back.

At of now, if you need to uninstall the app it would still need to be using the Admin console web UI. I also found that there is an existing report in Google's issue tracker where you can add more info for Google to analyze the feature request and possible develop an API method for this in the future.

#### References:

- [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247334593)
- [Method: tokens.delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/delete?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22laraportillo%40support-domain0011.xyz%22%2C%22clientId%22%3A%22961264221134-foqde0lca4la6b7s9kg4lkkj7prg9qn6.apps.googleusercontent.com%22%7D)